# How do I uninstall Speedbit Video Accelerator in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

My relative appears to have installed this program on Windows 7. It shows up near the clock, but there's no Uninstall command in its start menu folder, nor does it show up in the usual Windows Add/Remove Programs (or in CCleaner for that matter). So how do I uninstall Speedbit Video Accelerator?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I remove SPEEDbit Video Accelerator from my computer?
>
> You can uninstall SPEEDbit Video Accelerator by following the standard uninstall procedure.
>   From the Start menu, navigate to the SPEEDbit Video Accelerator program folder.
>   Click Uninstall SPEEDbit Video Accelerator.
>   Restart your computer.
>   Additionally you can uninstall SPEEDbit Video Accelerator using the Add/Remove Programs control panel.

Source: 
http://www.videoaccelerator.com/faq/